# How to have nice looking text fractions with sqrt in them

Tags: math-mode

Basically, I would like to do:

`[ sqrt( (some text here) + (texthere2) ) ] / [ texthere ]`

How do I do this properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Properly" is really a point of view.

I would generally go with:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
  \frac{\sqrt{(\text{some text here}) +
      (\text{texthere2})}}{\text{texthere}}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

So pretty much as you'd expect, unless you have some specific requirement that you need to fulfil, in which case you should be more specific about that.

Comment: @TheBitByte This is as plain as it gets, nothing special here! I'm not sure what you mean about quads, what makes you think I would need them here? Where would you put an em space?